# Strange height issue with revealing span in Safari only

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I'm having a problem with a span changing height in Safari only.

http://staging.isaidicanshout.com/4.0/#/proin-a-pretium-ipsum

On the top left is a "Projects" button that expands to reveal "Back to Projects" when you hover over it. In Chrome or Firefox, everything is fine. On Safari, the height and position of the span changes when you hover over it, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. Your link will probably be dead one day, while this question will stay forever.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's because you're using a mix of em's and vw which are generally pretty dynamic values

Especially be careful with vw, as it will cause you a lot of compatibility issues on IE and Edge:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Try to change the values (such as height and max-width) to temporary pixel values and see if that solves the problem. Then at least you're on the right track ;)

Answer (score 0):

I never found out why that was happening, but I ended up just changing them all to DIVs and that seemed to work.